# How to find eigenvectors and eigenvalues without numpy and scipy?

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I need to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors in python. numpy and scipy do not work. They both write `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`. I found out that to resolve the problem I need to check my blas/lapack. So, I thought that may be an easier way is to write/find a small function to solve the eigenvalue problem. Does anybody know if such solutions exist?

Comment: There is more than a one method but most of the time you'll end up performing matrix decomposition / diagonalization and without decent library for numerical computations it is hard to do it in a concise way. Moreover every straightforward method is ill-conditioned and without some optimization there is no guarantee you'll get something even remotely close to the real solution.

Comment: I'd also like a solution for this. I have to calculate the eigenvalues of small matrices (4x4), so speed is not a big issue. I can't use numpy/scipy (can't install it, for technical reasons that are beyond my control), but only pure python. I'd rather not implement an algorithm myself (I might as well solve it on paper and just implement the resulting equations!). There's got to be a simple snippet somewhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any efficient solution would use internally the same blas/lapack library. I still think that it won't be so hard to fix your libs.

But in case you find it easier, you can implement yourself any of those http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_analysis_topics#Eigenvalue_algorithms.

I suppose easiest to implement would be [power algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration), but doubt it would be efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sympy, the python computer algebra system, to solve the eigenvalue problem without native libraries using the Berkowitz method. It's not fast, but if you have a small number of small matrices, that won't be a problem.

Example:

```
>>> from sympy import Matrix
>>> m = Matrix([[10,2,3], [3,12,5], [5,5,8]])
>>> print m.eigenvals()
# this gets the eigenvalues along with their multiplicity
{10 - (-77/2 + sqrt(1019751)*I/18)**(1/3) - 50/(3*(-77/2 + sqrt(1019751)*I/18)**(1/3)): 1,
 10 - (-77/2 + sqrt(1019751)*I/18)**(1/3)*(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2) - 50/(3*(-77/2 + sqrt(1019751)*I/18)**(1/3)*(-1/2 + sqrt(3)*I/2)): 1,
 10 - 50/(3*(-77/2 + sqrt(1019751)*I/18)**(1/3)*(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2)) - (-77/2 + sqrt(1019751)*I/18)**(1/3)*(-1/2 - sqrt(3)*I/2): 1}
>>> print map(complex, m.eigenvals().keys())
[(8.374025140524024+2.117582368135751e-22j), (3.8835463038416105-2.117582368135751e-22j), (17.742428555634365-1.0587911840678754e-22j)]

# check with numpy
>>> import numpy as np
>>> print np.linalg.eigvals(np.array(m.tolist(), dtype=float))
array([ 17.74242856,   8.37402514,   3.8835463 ])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I actually managed to install numpy after all (over the mess of outdated python and library versions I have to deal with), but for the next time this might be handy.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a program to solve an eigenvalue problem is about 100 times as much work as fixing the library mismatch problem.